# Does it really make sense to have [uart] and [usart] tags instead of just [uart]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[usart](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usart) has [14 questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usart) while [uart](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uart) has [198 questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uart)

In most [usart](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usart) questions the fact that synchronous communication is possible, too, is not relevant, so [uart](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uart) would make more sense.

Therefore I think it would be a good idea to merge [usart](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usart) into [uart](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uart) and create a synonym.

Answer (score 2):

I had enough rep on the uart tag to suggest the synonym, now it needs up or down votes.

Edit: As PeterJ has pointed out, the voting is done at the Synonyms page for the [uart](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uart) tag https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/uart/synonyms

Alternatively, you can see all tag synonyms currently up for vote here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: Took me a while to remember where to vote, [it's here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/uart/synonyms) for anyone with a answer score of 5 on the tag.

Comment: The minimum 5 rep on the tag is an unnecessary nuissance IMO. Does not having the 5 rep mean I can't have an opinion on this?

Comment: @radagast, yes that's how it works. I had 6 on that tag so was able to vote but many times in the past have seen an obvious synonym I can't suggest / vote on so agree it's a pain. It's not 5 rep either - you need to have five upvoted questions or answers (minus any downvotes) on the tag.

Comment: @radagast mainly, yes. If you don't have a positive hand in the tag, then you don't get a potentially negative say in the tag's handling. Besides, +5 isn't too hard to get.

Comment: @Passerby: "Besides, +5 isn't too hard to get." I'm not too sure. It would require me to ask a question about UARTs and get an upvote on that (but I have no questions!) or add a superfluous answer to an existing thread, and despite that get upvotes. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @Passerby Upvoted the synonym.

Comment: The synonym is now active